Nav bar is duplicating entries when I try to remove them
I am the owner and admin of a SharePoint site that contains many subsites. We have a Table of Contents webpart tool that displays all the Project subsites within the Projects site. I made a new one today and added it to the quick navigation bar on the left and after I clicked save I noticed it duplicates a lot of entries on this ToC list. When I went back to try and delete the duplicates not only did it fail to delete but it duplicated even more entries into the ToC list!
ToC Image
I decided to try an delete the ToC webpart altogether and recreate it but that seems to fail as well. The problem appears to be when I set the webpart to use /sites/projects.
ToC Webpart Config
There is only a dozen or so projects that should populate. As you can see in the image above, there is 1 training subsite that should be populated in the ToC. Also, just to be clear, the ToC is set to only go 2 levels, so not subsequent subsites past layer two will appear in the list.
Has anyone seen this or has any tips? I've been racking my brain but everytime I try to make changes to potentially fix this I just end up populating more and more duplicate items into that ToC list.
I've tried rebuilding the ToC all together but that did not resolve the issue.
